# Jquery using functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

This code gives me error:

> TypeError: oneTime is not a function oneTime();

```
$ ->
  value = $("#car_addition_price_type").val()
  if value == "one_time"
    oneTime()
  else if value == "by_day"
    byDay()
  else
    hideAll()

  hideAll = ->
    $('#by_day').hide()
    $('#by_day input').val('')
    $('#max_price').hide()
    $('#max_price').val('')

  byDay = ->
    $("label[for='car_addition_price']").text("Cena/dzień")
    $('#max_price').show()
    $('#by_day').show()  

  oneTime = ->
    $('#by_day').show()
    $("label[for='car_addition_price']").text("Cena jednorazowa")
    $('#max_price').hide()
    $('#max_price input').val('')
```

Question is simple. Why?

Comment: Yep, stupid error. Thank's :)

Comment: Are these functions functions declaration or expression? For these functions to get hoisted, they have to be function declaration. So in your case declare your functions on top.

Comment: @AlexShilman `oneTime = ->` is converted to a function expression, the `var oneTime` gets hoisted (of course) but the assignment stays where it is.

Comment: So that's the problem. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to post this answer if it's not clear yet. The problem here is that your functions are functions expressions. So the declaration gets hoisted to the top but the assignment happens after your call. So the function doesnt exist at the time of your call. So in your case either make it a function declaration like so:

```
function oneTime(){}
```

or if you want to keep your functions as is, then just move all your functions to the top, above this block of code:

```
if value == "one_time"
oneTime()
 else if value == "by_day"
  byDay()
else
  hideAll()
```